# Objects in a Design/Runtime System

Tags: .net, visual-studio, design-patterns

Some environments lets you operate on objects by

- Designing them
- Running them

Are there any relevant design patterns (.NET or general) that cleanly separate the following?

- Designer logic / data
- Shared logic / data
- Runtime logic / data

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you mean by shared logic / data? By designing them (objects), I first think of UI controls, they can have design code, runtime code (also shown while designing - like control painting), and shared data (many controls let you populate their data which is also shown design-time).

As for a design pattern, I would say that here are many distinct responsibilities to be just one big design pattern.